# Breeding new child list from two same length lists, in order, without duplicates and splitting at random index

Tags: python, list, genetic-algorithm, perceptron

In this problem I am trying to create a new list of length `n` from two lists of length `n` each. I randomly select a subset of the first parent list (using start and end variables) and add them to the new list in the same positions in which they appeared in their corresponding list. Then I populate the remainder of the new list with elements from the second parent list in the order in which they appear, without duplicating any element that was selected from the first parent. The image explains it.

[image]

Here is my python code: a plane here is weights for a Perceptron model.

```
def breed(plane1, plane2):
    num_list = list(range(0, len(plane1)))
    random.shuffle(num_list)
    n1 = num_list[0]
    n2 = num_list[1]
    
    start = min(n1, n2)
    end = max(n1, n2)

    child = [None] * len(plane1)
    for i in range(start, end):
        child[i] = plane1[i]

    idx = (end) % len(plane2)   
    for i in range(len(plane2)):
        pos = (end + i) % len(plane2)

        if plane2[pos] not in child:
            child[idx] = plane2[pos]
            idx = (idx + 1) % len(plane2)

    return child
```

Can anyone recommend a different way that is efficient and concise?

Also, the end of random range is not included in the selection:

```
one = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
two = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
child = breed(one, two)
print(child)
```

start: 0
end: 7

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. It could probably be better, not using a while loop would be more elegant. I don't know if it covers all edge cases. I've split out the logic from the randomly generated numbers to make it easier to test.

```py
import random


def breed(plane1, plane2):
    assert len(plane1) == len(plane2)
    istart = random.randint(0, len(plane1) - 2)
    iend = random.randint(istart + 1, len(plane1) - 1)
    print(f"random indices: {istart} to {iend}")
    return generate_breed(plane1, plane2, istart, iend)


def generate_breed(plane1, plane2, istart, iend):
    child = [-1 for _ in plane1]
    child[istart : iend + 1] = plane1[istart : iend + 1]
    i = j = 0
    while True:
        if j == istart:
            j = iend + 1
        if j >= len(child):
            break
        if plane2[i] not in child:
            child[j] = plane2[i]
            j += 1
        i += 1
    return child


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1, p2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6]
    start, end = 2, 4
    assert generate_breed(p1, p2, start, end) == [7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
    assert generate_breed([1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1], 0, 2) == [1, 2, 3]

    # call like this, but answer is unpredictable due to randint call
    print(breed([1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Original answer was super wrong, after iterating over this for a while, this works, assuming lists don't have duplicates in themselves.

**Magic Numbers**

With generating the start and end, the magic -2 and magic +1 can be tuned if you want to set a min length. I set the min length here to 1.

```
def breed(plane1, plane2):
    i = randint(0, len(plane1) - 2)
    j = randint(i + 1, len(plane1))

    plane2 = [x for x in plane2 if x not in plane1[i:j]]
    child = plane2[0:i] + plane1[i:j] + plane2[i:len(plane1) - (j - i)]
    return child
```